# Issues in expand/collapse in Excel using MSSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, olap-cube

I am trying to browse a cube in Excel. When i try to expand the year dimension all 4 quarters displays well, but when i drill down further i got some display issues described as below, although the response which I am getting of the MDX query is fine

Please refer the below pictures for clarity:

when I expand 4 quarter of 2004 its working fine, but on expanding any other quarter of 2002, 2003 etc, 2002(dimension first member) is getting displayed. Please share your view or let me know if you require any more info.

One more thing, After generating response of drilldownmember query, excel again sends the MDSCHEMA_MEMBER query with hierarchy name in the memberuniquename tag...

Comment: I'm not seeing any pictures.  Can you post links to them and someone can edit them in?

Comment: Could it be that your quarters are not unique across the years, i. e. you have a key column for the quarter attribute containing something like 'Q1', and this is the same across different years?

Comment: @mmarie here you can see the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6rRZBXxD5g3MHVBQmZlV1pNWmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @FrankPl I have a unique name for each of the quarters, thus can uniquely identify which quarter belong to which year...

Comment: If you right-click on the blue table in the "Data Source View" pane of the dimension editor for your time dimension, and select "Explore data", do you see correct quarter numbers for the months? Which version of Analysis Services are you using? 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank U Guys for your time... @FrankPl yes the quarters were uniquely identified. Actually the issue was due to incorrect ordering of default property in the Axis Rowset. Got the idea from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725398(v=vs.85).aspx